# WPF Button touching issues on tablet PC

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, windows-8.1, tablet

I've created a WPF application for PCs/notebooks, and now I'm trying to make it usable on tablet PCs (Windows 8.1 is running on my tablet).
I've faced some differences between "touch" and "mouse" events (and I've read about their bubbling process etc.), and solved smaller problems, such as the `ScrollViewer`'s scrolling etc.

**1., Touching a control sometimes only highlights that, but does not "clicks"**

When I'm touching a control (`UserControl`, `Button` etc), sometimes it gets highlighted, but looks like the touch itself is not being performed. It's kinda misleading in case of buttons, since the binded `Command` wouldn't be executed, but it's background is being changed.

**2., Controls are being left highlighted after touching:**

When I'm touching a control (let's talk about a `Button` for example), the binded `Command` is being executed, but in most of the cases, the `Button` is still being highlighted until I touch the screen somewhere else. Maybe WPF thinks that my (non existing) mouse cursor is still staying above the control?

*Note: please note that, the application is being used on desktop devices mainly, so I must be able to use the controls with keyboard + mouse as well.*

Thanks for looking into it!

Comment: I remember having this exact same problem. I think I solved it by using touchdown, or maybe stylusdown?

Comment: I've tried to set the `Handled` property to `true` during those events, and/or set the background colour to the expected etc., but it didn't solve the problem(s). There must be some little "user interactivity flow" trick during the stylus/touch/mouse events which I'm missing - I guess -, because of the lack of my tablet development experience.

Comment: @Kai have you resolved this issue? If yes then how? I am also getting the same issue and tried many solutions but does not worked.

Comment: @KAI did you solve the isue ? Having the same problem, works perfect on desktop but on tablet it doesn't work as it should

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I solved it on a different way, but I don't have access to that codebase anymore. I remember playing with the bubbling of the events and maybe I even had to switch from `ICommand`s to use built-in `Click` events. My solution worked, but that felt like a workaround. :/